# WPF MVVM Child View Property share question

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have 2 UserControl and their ViewModel.
I created a third UserControl that is common to the the first ones (a listbox).

I have a SelectedContact of listbox SelectedItem binded to a property in UserControl 3.

Questions:
-Where SelectedContact should be defined ? In the Hosting User controls (1 and 2) or in the common one (n°3) ?
-I have implemented it in UC1 and UC2. It works BUT in UC3 even when i define it, i can't access it, it is always null.  Only the one in UC1  gets the selection.

I'm not clear on this... Can someone point me to some idea ?
Thanks
John

Answer (score 2):

Your SelectedContact should be stored in your ViewModel